# Audit Service using MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, audit-trail, audit-logging

I have a requirement to create an Audit service. All the changes in The transactional system will be captured at the service layer and will be sent to a JMS queue as a JSON object. This audit service will take this JSON object and is tasked to store it.The traditional way is to have RDBMS with tables that mirror the transactional DB and write these changes into it.I was thinking of an alternative approach of using MongoDB to write the diffs something like below.

db.users.insert({
  chd_dt:2016-05-26T20:25:12.014Z
  user_id: 'abc001',
  age: 39,
  status: 'A'
})

db.users.insert({
  chd_dt:2016-05-27T20:25:12.014Z
  user_id: 'abc001',
  status: 'X'
})

I will also have to make some reporting style screens on top of this datastore so that business can use them.

Any suggestion in this regard are highly appreciated.

Comment: it is very broad question - please narrow your problem.